# Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined Konva.js

Tags: reactjs, find, react-konva, konva

I'm trying to find object by using method `find`. It is only a part of code, just to demonstrate issue. In general I need to find object from array of `Shapes` from `Konva` framework. I got it by using refs after rendering functional component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Konva from "konva";
import { Stage, Layer, Text, Circle } from "react-konva";

import { ArrowComp } from "./Arrow";
import { useInterval } from "../hooks/useInterval";

const Graph = props => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        circles: ConvertMatrix(matrix).circles,
    });
        const circles = ref.current.find(".circle");
    const stageRef = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        const circles = stageRef.current.find(".circle");
        const finded = circles.find((circle) => circle.attrs.radius < 50)
    }, []);

    return (
        <Stage
            width={window.innerWidth}
            height={window.innerHeight}
            className="container"
            ref={stageRef}
        >
            <Layer>
                   <Circle
                      shadowBlur={10}
                      x={150}
                      y={200}

                      radius={circle.r || 40}
                      fill="yellow"
                      name={"circle"}
                      id={1}
                    /> 
                     <Circle
                      shadowBlur={10}
                      x={150}
                      y={150}
                      radius={40}
                      fill="yellow"
                      name={"circle"}
                      id={2}
                    />        
            </Layer>
        </Stage>
    );
};


ReactDOM.render(<Graph />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

and I get error in lib. Is it konva framework library? How can I find element from array by the other way?

```
     16 |     var len = this.length, i;
  17 |     var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  18 |     for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
> 19 |         this[i][methodName].apply(this[i], args);
     | ^  20 |     }
  21 |     return this;
  22 | };
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
Collection. [as find]

Thats my first question on StackOwerflow, sorry for the question not quite in the format. 
I made an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-haibt-l2c9q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

UPD: solved problem by using `findIndex` and got value by circles[index]. But 1 questionl left: is it bug of the library(framework)?

Comment: What is `circles`, is it an array of objects? Do you have a sample?

Comment: @Jayce444 yes, circles its an array of objects. Sample, I'm tried to make it, but I failed. I can't connect `konva` lib to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). If you help me, I'll make it. Thanks

Comment: @Jayce444 I made the example. You can see it at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `circles` variable is not an array. `stage.find(selectors)` returns a [Konva.Collection](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Collection.html). It works a bit differently from the Array. If you want to have an array just use:

```js
circles.toArray().find((circle) => circle.radius() < 50);
```